# Missing matching quote with su -c in bash script

Tags: bash, su

I want to write something like

```
EXEC="sudo su -m root -c \"java Something\""
$EXEC &
```

But i get the following error:

```
Something": -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
Something": -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

If I write the command on the command line it executes. If I have it stored in a variable and trying to extrapolate it - it does not. Why?

Comment: Try this: `for w in $EXEC ; do echo $w; done` and you shall see.

Comment: @Mat: not the same question - the problem there is that \' has no meaning in '...', while \" does has meaning in "...". Thanks, but I know how to use the search.

Comment: @n.m. I don't get your point. for-in just splits a string on spaces without taking into account quotes. If I write the command on a command line it executes. What's the difference between writing that command and having it stored in a variable and trying to extrapolate it?

Comment: The difference is that the result of parameter expansion is only subject to word splitting at blanks (or IFS, see 3.5.7 in the reference manual). The usual complex tokenization happens at the time of input *reading* from the input file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
exec="ls -l \"/a b c\""
$exec
```

You will see something like:

```
ls: cannot access "/a: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access b: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access c": No such file or directory
```

Which shows exactly where the problem is - that is - expansion of variable is done **after** word splitting.

To make it work, you can use eval:

```
=$ eval "$exec"
ls: cannot access /a b c: No such file or directory
```

or even:

```
=$ sh -c "$exec"
```

Or better yet, don't make such commands to run. Not sure what is the purpose of it, but think about avoiding building full command lines in variables.